# ReportID in a HID report descriptor

Tags: usb, hid, descriptor

i am a little confused about how ReportID works. According to the HID documentation, only main items "generate" data. All other items define characteristics of those data. But ReportID defined as a global item seems to work differently: Look at this report descriptor of a joystick:

```
Usage Page (Generic Desktop)    05 01 
Usage (Joystick)    09 04 
Collection (Application)    A1 01 
    Collection (Logical)    A1 02 
        Report ID (1)   85 01 
        Report Size (8)     75 08 
        Report Count (1)    95 01 
        Logical Minimum (0)     15 00 
        Logical Maximum (255)   26 FF 00 
        Input (Cnst,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)     81 03 
        Report Size (1)     75 01 
        Report Count (19)   95 13 
        Logical Minimum (0)     15 00 
        Logical Maximum (1)     25 01 
        Physical Minimum (0)    35 00 
        Physical Maximum (1)    45 01 
        Usage Page (Button)     05 09 
        Usage Minimum (Button 1)    19 01 
        Usage Maximum (Button 19)   29 13 
        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)     81 02
```

When the device send his report, i expected to have one byte for the report id followed by 3 bytes for the buttons state. But this is not the case: i receive one byte for the report id, followed by a null byte and then followed by 3 bytes for the buttons state.

Does it mean i should threat ReportID as a main item instead of a global item ?

Thanks,

Willy.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between GLOBAL and LOCAL items is that the value of a GLOBAL item is retained when the next MAIN item is encountered sequentially during parsing but the value of LOCAL items are not retained. The values of all LOCAL items are reset to their default state when the next MAIN item is encountered. The REPORT_ID is a GLOBAL item and that just means that once you set it, its value stays the same until you set it to another value.

The example you posted will be parsed as the following structure (using C language syntax):

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Generic Desktop Page inputReport 01 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x01 (1)
                                                     // Collection: CA:Joystick
  uint8_t  pad_1;                                    // Pad
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton1 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090001: Button 1 Primary/trigger, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton2 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090002: Button 2 Secondary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton3 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090003: Button 3 Tertiary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton4 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090004: Button 4, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton5 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090005: Button 5, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton6 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090006: Button 6, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton7 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090007: Button 7, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton8 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090008: Button 8, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton9 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090009: Button 9, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton10 : 1;                 // Usage 0x0009000A: Button 10, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton11 : 1;                 // Usage 0x0009000B: Button 11, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton12 : 1;                 // Usage 0x0009000C: Button 12, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton13 : 1;                 // Usage 0x0009000D: Button 13, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton14 : 1;                 // Usage 0x0009000E: Button 14, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton15 : 1;                 // Usage 0x0009000F: Button 15, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton16 : 1;                 // Usage 0x00090010: Button 16, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton17 : 1;                 // Usage 0x00090011: Button 17, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton18 : 1;                 // Usage 0x00090012: Button 18, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton19 : 1;                 // Usage 0x00090013: Button 19, Value = 0 to 1
} inputReport01_t;
```

Which looks like the following in memory:

```
   Bit:    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0  
        .---------------------------------------.
Byte 0  |     Report ID (0x01)                  |
        |---------------------------------------|
Byte 1  |     Pad                               |
        |---------------------------------------|
Byte 2  |  8 |  7 |  6 |  5 |  4 |  3 |  2 |  1 | Buttons 1 to 8
        |---------------------------------------|
Byte 3  | 16 | 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 |  9 | Buttons 9 to 16
        |---------------------------------------|
Byte 4  |    |    |    |    |    | 19 | 18 | 17 | Buttons 17 to 19
        '---------------------------------------'
```

In other words, what you are seeing is the correct layout for the specified report descriptor. You may have misunderstood the significance of the `Input (Cnst,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)     81 03` item - which defines a "constant" byte - that is, a byte that contains no information but occupies space in the report transmitted on the wire.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

My confusion came from the documentation.

Take a look on the "Device Class Definition for Human Interface Devices (HID)" document.

Page 28, you can read: "Datatype Main items are used to create a field within a report ..."
and page 35, you can read: "Global items describe rather than define ..."

As TargetID is not a main item, i didn't expect it to create space in the report, like Input item does.

Comment: Yes, the USB specifications are quite difficult to digest. Important information in them is easy to miss. In this instance Section 5.6 of that document has this gem: " If a device has multiple report structures, all data transfers start with a 1-byte identifier prefix that indicates which report structure applies to the transfer. This allows the class driver to distinguish incoming pointer data from keyboard data by examining the transfer prefix."